# How to destroy a started session without warning?

Tags: php, session

I'm going mad !

```
function initialize() {
 session_start(); //EDITED
 if(blnSessionIsStarted() && !session_destroy()) // Destroy session on disk
  return false;
 ...
 if(!blnSessionIsStarted() && !session_start()) //EDITED
  return false; //EDITED
 } //EDITED

function blnSessionIsStarted()
{
 //From: http://uk3.php.net/manual/en/function.session-status.php#113468
 if ( php_sapi_name() !== 'cli' ) {
  if ( version_compare(phpversion(), '5.4.0', '>=') ) {
  return session_status() === PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE ? TRUE : FALSE;
  } else {
   return session_id() == '' ? FALSE : TRUE;
  }
 }
 return FALSE;
}
```

In my site, this returns a

```
PHP WARNING (2): session_destroy(): Trying to destroy uninitialized session
```

Within `blnSessionIsStarted()`, `session_id()` contains a non-empty session string, hence the function returns true. I am using PHP 5.3.10. I want to get rid of this warning, but everywhere I read, the code used seems to be the best practice out there. Am I missing something?

**EDIT**
Following the advice from some users and looking up their feedback, I added some edited lines.
However, now it's returning another error (notice) 'PHP NOTICE (8): A session had already been started - ignoring session_start()'.

But, these changes are irrelevant: Why does blnSessionIsStarted() return true even though the session has not been started yet, and if so, how does one accurately detect that the session has been started, without enforcing the call to session_start() before? And why is there a notice thrown when session_start() is re-called, and how to detect that a session_start() cant be called, even though blnSessionIsStarted() says it is no longer started?

Comment: Do you call `session_start()` anywhere? before calling `initialize()`?

Comment: @Kleskowy is right! start the session before calling `initialize()` or  before the if() in function initialize()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call, `session_start();` first. There is no session right now.